# How to turn a list of json Strings into one JsonNode/Object in java

Tags: java, json, api, jackson

I have some data that is put into a List and I am trying to use the ObjectMapper class from Jackson to map them into a single string so that I can then convert them into a JsonNode to return. The issue is that I do not want to manually hardcode commas for the mapper to distinguish each element.

The list returned from the database looks like this:

```
0: {"someKey": "someVal"}
1: {"someKey2": "someVal2"}
2: {"someKey3": "someVal3"}
```

```
List<String> responseList = dao.getDetails(something, something2);

for(String row : responseList){
 responseString += row;
}

jsonNode = mapper.readTree(responseString);
```

The resulting jsonNode of that would be :

```
{"someKey": "someVal"}
```

the objectmapper ignores the other two values because the string doesn't have any commas to distinguish them. How can I get a single JsonNode response for a list of strings without having to manually insert commas and brackets? thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of joining everything into a String, you can parse individually each row and add it manually to an `ArrayNode`, like this:

```
List<String> responseList = Arrays.asList(
        "{\"someKey\": \"someVal\"}",
        "{\"someKey2\": \"someVal2\"}",
        "{\"someKey3\": \"someVal3\"}");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode arr = mapper.createArrayNode();
for (String row : responseList) {
    arr.add(mapper.readTree(row));
}
System.out.println(arr);
```